# Estimate for the co-volume of discs centered at lattice points in the plane?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-lattices

Suppose I have a unimodular lattice $\Lambda = A \mathbb{Z^2}$ ($A\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$) in the plane. I place a disc of fixed radius, $r$, around each point of $\Lambda$,  so that I have a union of (possibly overlapping) discs $$\bigcup_{v\in \Lambda} \mathbb{D}^2(v, r) := \mathfrak{D}$$ and I want to estimate the covolume of $\mathfrak{D}$, i.e. the measure of $\mathfrak{D}\cap P$, where P is any fundamental parallelogram. Are there any known estimates for this covolume in terms of $A$ and $r$?  I'm quite out of my depth, so any vague suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: If there is no overlap, it is just the area of one disc. Above the covering radius, the whole tile.

Comment: Tim, what are you trying to get to?

Comment: @WillJagy   Thanks again.  The disks may overlap without covering the whole plane though, right?  Basically I'm trying to get some sort of bound for the rate of decay (as r gets large) of the Haar measure of the set of grids (thought of as elements of $\mathbb{R}\ltimes SL(2, \mathbb{R})/ \mathbb{Z}\ltimes SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$) which admit a disjoint disk of radius r centered at the origin. Since the space of grids is a torus bundle over the space of lattices, I thought I'd try to get a handle on the measure of the set lying in a particular fibre. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Right, area of one disc until, i guess, half the shortest lattice vector, then messy intermediate behavior (but continuous and monotonic) and then constant. In dimension 2, worth just drawing some actual pictures of parallelograms and circles on paper. that's what i did to get an explicit formula for the covering radius in dimension 2.

Comment: @WillJagy I guess my main concern was that there would be interference from discs centered at points that aren't vertices of my chosen parallelogram. I.e. points in my parallalogram closer to a lattice point that isn't a vertex of the parallelogram than they are to any of the vertices of the parallelogram. But I'll think a bit more and draw some pictures. Thanks!